# Find + ls -lT in compound command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, find

To get the full timestamp of a file, I can do:

```
$ ls -lT
```

However, when I try the following:

```
find . -ls -lT
```

I get an `find: -lt: unknown primary or operator` (using `find . -ls` works).

What would be the correct way to use the `find` + `ls -lT` command?

Comment: What OS are you on, which version of ls? **ls: option requires an argument -- 'T'**   Also, the ls in find is different from the OSes.  Try -exec ls -1T {}+

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The find "-ls" option isn't running ls and doesn't accept all its arguments.  That said, I don't know why you want the -T argument, which is an obscure thing involving tab stops that I had to look up.  But broadly, you just want to run a command ("ls -lT" in this case) on a bunch of files found by find.  So any of the following should work: `find . -type f | xargs -n1 ls -lT` or `find . -type f -exec ls -lT {} ';'` or `for i in $(find . -type f); do ls -lT $i; done`.

Or, for the special case of ls that takes more than one command line argument, just `find . -type f | xargs ls -lT`

Comment: You should use `find . -type f -exec ls -lT {} +` (efficient) or `find . -type f -exec ls -lT {} ';'` (compatible with pre-posix tools). The find/xargs variant and the for loop will fail on filenames with spaces and such

Comment: All true, though that gets us into -print0/-0 and all sorts of other minutiae.  My point was really just to say that this is a general problem and it has a big list of general solutions.

Answer (score 3):

If you're parsing the output of `ls`, you're doing it wrong.  There's always a better way to interface with the filesystem than parsing human-readable output.

I'm not sure what you mean by the "full timestamp of the file", but if you want, say, the last modification time, use `stat`.

```
stat --printf='%x' foo 
2013-01-29 13:33:32.000000000 -0600
```

Run `man stat` to see all the other formatting options in the `--printf` argument.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. How would I then get the `stat` for hundreds of thousands of files (which I'll need to load into a db)?